# YII2 gridview sort and filter sum of values of two columns

Tags: gridview, yii2

I successfully displayed the 3 columns in the gridview. the `attr1`, `attr2`, and the sum of the 2 attributes. `attr1` and `attr2` are from the database and the 3rd column is their sum. How to make the sorting and filtering work.

Here is the gridview.

```
[
  'attribute'=>'total',
  'label'=>'TOTAL',
  'value'=>function($model){
  return $model->attr1+ $model->attr2;
  },
],
```

i have tried this in the searchmodel

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['total'] = [
        'asc' => [$this->attr1 + $this->attr1 => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => [$this->attr1 + $this->attr2 => SORT_DESC],
        ];
```

and

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
            'total' => $this->total,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ADD(table_name.column1, table_name.column2)', $this->total])
```

may be work?